# taking more time to load page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was running a cron job daily to create records .

I had 300 users and every day i will be creating 20 records for each user. So total - 6000 records daily .(its a daily food item records )

Now when user login and view the page  , it was taking more time and deep slow .

So for now i am deleting the records which are 30 days old daily.but this hasnt solved my issue

Can any tell me how to overcome this and increase performance ?

thanks,
sri

Comment: please post code, querres and model relationships.

Comment: it could be a lack of indexes in your DB too, please post your schema too (indexes included)

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be reformatted with less number of loops.